# merging many DBF (csv) files into one, appending along column

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, dbf

I've been going over many cvs file merging and haven't had much luck. here my current script. The result are only 1 data file being written or the files being append to rows and not columns . I added the \n to try avoid the Row problem.

```
import os
yolo = []
location = os.listdir("C:\Users\jcm\Desktop\RO")
for filename in location:
    #print  filename
    if "(Wide)" in filename:
        yolo.append(filename)
total = len(yolo)
with open("out4.dbf", "a") as f:

    for num in yolo:
        for line in open("C:\Users\jcm\Desktop\RO\\" +num,"rb"):
             f.write(line+"\n")
             print line+"\n"
```

The print line\n is printing all the data, but doesn't add it to the appending file.
This is database file format. Ive found ways to format DBF into csv, but not merging thousands of data points. First row is field names, 2nd row is data type, 3rd+ is data.

Here the code I'm using to filter DBF files. I've added my code at the bottom that I'm using.

```
import struct, datetime, decimal, itertools      
def dbfreader(f):
    """Returns an iterator over records in a Xbase DBF file.

    The first row returned contains the field names.
    The second row contains field specs: (type, size, decimal places).
    Subsequent rows contain the data records.
    If a record is marked as deleted, it is skipped.

    File should be opened for binary reads.

    """
    # See DBF format spec at:
    #     http://www.pgts.com.au/download/public/xbase.htm#DBF_STRUCT

    numrec, lenheader = struct.unpack('<xxxxLH22x', f.read(32))    
    numfields = (lenheader - 33) // 32

    fields = []
    for fieldno in xrange(numfields):
        name, typ, size, deci = struct.unpack('<11sc4xBB14x', f.read(32))
        name = name.replace('\0', '')       # eliminate NULs from string   
        fields.append((name, typ, size, deci))
    yield [field[0] for field in fields]
    yield [tuple(field[1:]) for field in fields]

    terminator = f.read(1)
    assert terminator == '\r'

    fields.insert(0, ('DeletionFlag', 'C', 1, 0))
    fmt = ''.join(['%ds' % fieldinfo[2] for fieldinfo in fields])
    fmtsiz = struct.calcsize(fmt)
    for i in xrange(numrec):
        record = struct.unpack(fmt, f.read(fmtsiz))
        if record[0] != ' ':
            continue                        # deleted record
        result = []
        for (name, typ, size, deci), value in itertools.izip(fields, record):
            if name == 'DeletionFlag':
                continue
            if typ == "N":
                value = value.replace('\0', '').lstrip()
                value = value.replace(' ', '').lstrip()
                if value == '':
                    value = 0

                elif deci:
                    value = decimal.Decimal(value)
                else:
                    value = int(value)
            elif typ == 'DATE':
                y, m, d = int(value[:4]), int(value[4:6]), int(value[6:8])
                value = datetime.date(y, m, d)
            elif typ == 'L':
                value = (value in 'YyTt' and 'T') or (value in 'NnFf' and 'F') or '?'
            elif typ == 'F':
                value = float(value)
            result.append(value)
        yield result
yoloies = []
yolo = []
yolos = [] 
def dbfwriter(f, fieldnames, fieldspecs, records):

    """ Return a string suitable for writing directly to a binary dbf file.

    File f should be open for writing in a binary mode.

    Fieldnames should be no longer than ten characters and not include \x00.
    Fieldspecs are in the form (type, size, deci) where
        type is one of:
            C for ascii character data
            M for ascii character memo data (real memo fields not supported)
            D for datetime objects
            N for ints or decimal objects
            L for logical values 'T', 'F', or '?'
        size is the field width
        deci is the number of decimal places in the provided decimal object
    Records can be an iterable over the records (sequences of field values).

    """
    # header info
    ver = 3
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    yr, mon, day = now.year-1900, now.month, now.day
    numrec = len(records)
    numfields = len(fieldspecs)
    lenheader = numfields * 32 + 33
    lenrecord = sum(field[1] for field in fieldspecs) + 1
    hdr = struct.pack('<BBBBLHH20x', ver, yr, mon, day, numrec, lenheader, lenrecord)
    f.write(hdr)

    # field specs
    for name, (typ, size, deci) in itertools.izip(fieldnames, fieldspecs):
        name = name.ljust(11, '\x00')
        fld = struct.pack('<11sc4xBB14x', name, typ, size, deci)
        f.write(fld)

    # terminator
    f.write('\r')

    # records
    for record in records:
        f.write(' ')                        # deletion flag
        for (typ, size, deci), value in itertools.izip(fieldspecs, record):
            if typ == "N":
                value = str(value).rjust(size, ' ')

            elif typ == 'DATE':
                value = value.strftime('%Y%m%d')
            elif typ == 'L':
                value = str(value)[0].upper()
            else:
                value = str(value)[:size].ljust(size, ' ')
            #assert len(value) == size
            f.write(value)
        yoloies.append(record[1])    
        yolo.append(int(float(record[6])))
        yolos.append(int(record[0]))
    # End of file
    f.write('\x1A')


# -------------------------------------------------------
# Example calls
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys, csv
    from cStringIO import StringIO
    from operator import itemgetter

    # Read a database
    filename = 'out.dbf'      
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        filename = sys.argv[1]
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    db = list(dbfreader(f))
    f.close()
    for record in db:
        print record
    fieldnames, fieldspecs, records = db[0], db[1], db[2:]

    # Alter the database
    #del records[0]
    #records.sort(key=itemgetter(4))

    # Remove a field
    #del fieldnames[3]
    #del fieldspecs[3]
    #records = [rec[1:] for rec in records]

    # Create a new DBF
    f = StringIO()
    dbfwriter(f, fieldnames, fieldspecs, records)

    # Read the data back from the new DBF
    print '-' * 20    
    f.seek(0)
    for line in dbfreader(f):
        print line
    f.close()

    # Convert to CSV
    print '.' * 20    
    f = StringIO()
    csv.writer(f).writerow(fieldnames)    
    csv.writer(f).writerows(records)
    print "break"
    #filename = 'MyDBF.cvs'
    #g = open(filename, 'w')
    #g.write(f.getvalue())
    print f.getvalue()
    f.close()
    print "break"
    #jcm code
    intensities = []
    intensities = zip(yolos,yoloies, yolo)

    print intensities
    with open("yolosss.csv", "w") as out_file:
        for date, time, intensity in zip(yolos, yoloies, yolo):
            out_file.write("%i,%s,%i\n" % (date, time, intensity))
            print "done"
```

Data sample.

```
['Date', 'Time', 'Millitm', 'Marker', '0', 'Sts_00', '1', 'Sts_01', '2', 'Sts_02', '3', 'Sts_03', '4', 'Sts_04', '5', 'Sts_05', '6', 'Sts_06', '7', 'Sts_07', '8', 'Sts_08', '9', 'Sts_09', '10', 'Sts_10', '11', 'Sts_11', '12', 'Sts_12']
[('D', 8, 0), ('C', 8, 0), ('N', 3, 0), ('C', 1, 0), ('F', 17, 8), ('C', 1, 0), ('F', 17, 8), ('C', 1, 0), ('F', 17, 8), ('C', 1, 0), ('F', 1, 0), ('C', 1, 0), ('F', 1, 0), ('C', 1, 0), ('F', 17, 8), ('C', 1, 0), ('F', 17, 8), ('C', 1, 0), ('F', 17, 8), ('C', 1, 0), ('F', 17, 8), ('C', 1, 0), ('F', 17, 8), ('C', 1, 0), ('F', 17, 8), ('C', 1, 0), ('F', 17, 8), ('C', 1, 0), ('F', 17, 8), ('C', 1, 0)]
['20130531', '00:00:28', 977, 'B', 548.84643555, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 83.11103058, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.93495178, ' ', 7.26524115, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 231.49482727, ' ', 16.30217171, ' ', 12.48698235, ' ']
['20130531', '00:05:13', 577, ' ', 571.55731201, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 81.2725296, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.93943787, ' ', 7.26580191, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 230.02883911, ' ', 16.31218529, ' ', 12.94760895, ' ']
['20130531', '00:20:13', 701, ' ', 547.88513184, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 82.43811798, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.9360733, ' ', 7.27926016, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 230.24513245, ' ', 16.202034, ' ', 11.91620636, ' ']
['20130531', '00:35:13', 885, ' ', 613.19396973, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 81.4948349, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.9276619, ' ', 7.29215765, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 230.04084778, ' ', 16.14195251, ' ', 11.29536152, ' ']
['20130531', '00:50:14', 60, ' ', 466.35424805, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 79.93270874, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.92541885, ' ', 7.3028121, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 230.50949097, ' ', 16.02178955, ' ', 10.67451763, ' ']
['20130531', '01:05:14', 174, ' ', 449.89187622, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 83.67579651, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.92373657, ' ', 7.31290579, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 233.10502625, ' ', 15.83153057, ' ', 10.29399967, ' ']
['20130531', '01:20:15', 19, ' ', 444.96517944, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 76.59817505, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.92429733, ' ', 7.31010199, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 229.95674133, ' ', 15.71136761, ' ', 10.48425865, ' ']
['20130531', '01:35:15', 94, ' ', 428.08221436, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 83.30929565, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.92373657, ' ', 7.29944754, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 232.22782898, ' ', 15.61123085, ' ', 11.28534794, ' ']
['20130531', '01:50:15', 238, ' ', 485.58041382, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 81.09828949, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.93831635, ' ', 7.30785894, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 229.75245667, ' ', 15.39093208, ' ', 10.68453121, ' ']
['20130531', '02:05:15', 382, ' ', 437.81542969, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 82.19178009, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.93102646, ' ', 7.3213172, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 232.1557312, ' ', 15.23071384, ' ', 9.82335949, ' ']
['20130531', '02:20:15', 687, ' ', 412.64120483, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 84.45085144, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.91925049, ' ', 7.33533621, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 231.02618408, ' ', 15.11054993, ' ', 9.17247486, ' ']
['20130531', '02:35:15', 841, ' ', 383.62173462, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 81.18240356, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.9119606, ' ', 7.34318686, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 231.53088379, ' ', 15.01041412, ' ', 8.6918211, ' ']
['20130531', '02:50:15', 986, ' ', 404.04953003, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 79.95674133, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.90186691, ' ', 7.33982229, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 230.24513245, ' ', 14.82015514, ' ', 8.9221344, ' ']
['20130531', '03:05:16', 120, ' ', 392.8142395, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 81.9334259, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.90298843, ' ', 7.32019567, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 230.22109985, ' ', 14.53977394, ' ', 9.99359131, ' ']
['20130531', '03:20:16', 515, ' ', 494.0519104, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 82.09564972, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.91812897, ' ', 7.30056906, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 233.12905884, ' ', 14.29944706, ' ', 10.74461269, ' ']
['20130531', '03:35:18', 381, ' ', 517.84429932, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 82.45013428, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.92541885, ' ', 7.28991461, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 232.68444824, ' ', 14.11920166, ' ', 10.87478924, ' ']
['20130531', '03:50:18', 946, ' ', 488.16390991, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 81.68108368, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.93214798, ' ', 7.28486776, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 231.71112061, ' ', 13.8688612, ' ', 11.23528004, ' ']
['20130531', '04:05:19', 141, ' ', 508.65179443, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 80.45542145, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.93214798, ' ', 7.28542852, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 229.87261963, ' ', 13.66858959, ' ', 11.29536152, ' ']
['20130531', '04:20:19', 435, ' ', 553.83325195, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.89233398, ' ', 7.27701712, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.04806537, ' ', 14.34951496, ' ', 24.47328377, ' ']
['20130531', '04:21:56', 224, 'E', 542.41772461, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.87607145, ' ', 7.27197027, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.04806537, ' ', 14.98037338, ' ', 24.40318871, ' ']
['20130531', '05:17:14', 780, 'B', 0.0, 'U', 0.0, 'U', 0.0, 'U', 0.0, 'U', 0.0, 'U', 0.0, 'U', 0.0, 'U', 0.0, 'U', 0.0, 'U', 0.0, 'U', 0.0, 'U', 0.0, 'U', 0.0, 'U']
['20130531', '05:32:15', 505, ' ', 554.61431885, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.8906517, ' ', 7.24337101, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.04806537, ' ', 86.66786957, ' ', 12.76736355, ' ']
['20130531', '05:47:15', 669, ' ', 546.20288086, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.01201634, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.89345551, ' ', 7.24337101, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.06008171, ' ', 163.59248352, ' ', 12.31675053, ' ']
['20130531', '06:02:15', 864, ' ', 512.49700928, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.89289474, ' ', 7.24168873, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.04806537, ' ', 184.21052551, ' ', 12.16654682, ' ']
['20130531', '06:17:16', 879, ' ', 417.08724976, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.89738083, ' ', 7.24056721, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.04806537, ' ', 210.36610413, ' ', 12.18657398, ' ']
['20130531', '06:32:17', 104, ' ', 450.612854, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.89233398, ' ', 7.24112797, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.04806537, ' ', 238.79475403, ' ', 12.06641006, ' ']
['20130531', '06:47:18', 530, ' ', 539.05310059, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 6.88896894, ' ', 7.24112797, ' ', 0.0, ' ', 0.06008171, ' ', 249.29904175, ' ', 12.05639648, ' ']
```

data sample from notepad

```
   á¢                     DATE       D                   TIME       C                   MILLITM    N                  MARKER     C                   N0         N                  STS_00     C                   N1         N    
              STS_01     C                   N2         N                  STS_02     C                   N3         N                  STS_03     C                   N4         N                  STS_04     C                   N5         N    
              STS_05     C                   N6         N    
              STS_06     C                   N7         N    
              STS_07     C                   N8         N    
              STS_08     C                   N9         N    
              STS_09     C                   N10        N                  STS_10     C                   N11        N                  STS_11     C                   N12        N                  STS_12     C                   
 2013053100:00:28977.00B548.84643555 0.00000000 83.11103058 0.00 0.00 0.00000000 0.00000000 6.93495178 7.26524115 0.00000000 231.49482727 16.30217171 12.48698235  2013053100:05:13577.00 571.55731201 0.00000000 81.27252960 0.00 0.00 0.00000000 0.00000000 6.93943787 7.26580191 0.00000000 230.02883911 16.31218529 12.94760895  2013053100:20:13701.00 547.88513184 0.00000000 82.43811798 0.00 0.00 0.00000000 0.00000000 6.93607330 7.27926016 0.00000000 230.24513245 16.20203400 11.91620636  2013053100:35:13885.00 613.19396973 0.00000000 81.49483490 0.00 0.00 0.00000000 0.00000000 6.92766190 7.29215765 0.00000000 230.04084778 16.14195251 11.29536152  2013053100:50:14 60.00 466.35424805 0.00000000 79.93270874 0.00 0.00 0.00000000 0.00000000 6.92541885 7.30281210 0.00000000 230.50949097 16.02178955 10.67451763
```

Comment: The data sample that you have added -- is it what you are writing or what you are reading?

Comment: The data is print statement from the code 2nd code I submited. It wasn't really readable opening in note pad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only suggestion I can offer at the moment is use [my dbf module](http://python.org/pypi/dbf) instead of writing your own.

If you could give examples of two data files and an example of what they should look like in the final dbf file, I could offer more.

Here's your code, much simplified:

```
import dbf      
import os
from glob import glob

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get interesting dbf file names
    ROfiles = set(glob(r"C:\Users\jcm\Desktop\RO\*(Wide)*.dbf"))

    merged_dbf = None

    # Read a database
    for dbf_filename in ROfiles:
        with dbf.Table(dbf_filename) as table:

            # create merged dbf if it hasn't been
            if merged_dbf is None:
                merged_dbf = table.new('merged')

            with merged_dbf:
                # merge in records
                for record in table:
                    merged_dbf.append(record)

                #Create a new csv from merged_dbf
                dbf.export(merged_dbf, 'catwomen')
```

Comment: Thanks for showing great example, if you could show a simplified example of my latest answer I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt of inputs and selecting columns desired.

```
import struct, datetime, decimal, itertools      
import os
import csv
location = os.listdir("C:\Users\jcm\Desktop\RO")

ROfiles = []
Nameoutput = "YouDidntNameMe"
Nameoutput = (raw_input("Name output file:"))
daytime = (raw_input("Do you want Date/Time Fields? yes or no: "))

num_lists = int(raw_input("How many Data Fields do you want? 1-6:"))
if num_lists >= 0:
                xone = 0
                xone = int(raw_input("which Row do you want for Fieldone?"))
if num_lists >= 2:
                xtwo = 0
                xtwo = int(raw_input("which Row do you want for Fieldtwo?"))
if num_lists >= 3:
                xthree = 0
                xthree = int(raw_input("which Row do you want for Fieldthree?"))
if num_lists >= 4:
                xfour = 0
                xfour = int(raw_input("which Row do you want for Fieldfour?"))
if num_lists >= 5:
                xfive = 0
                xfive = int(raw_input("which Row do you want for Fieldfive?"))
if num_lists >= 6:
                xsix = 0
                xsix = int(raw_input("which Row do you want for Fielsix?"))



location = os.listdir("C:\Users\jcm\Desktop\RO")
for filename in location:

        if "(Wide)" in filename and filename not in ROfiles: #There is 2 dbf files one named Tag and another Wide.
            ROfiles.append(filename)
total = len(ROfiles)    
def dbfreader(f):
    """Returns an iterator over records in a Xbase DBF file.

    The first row returned contains the field names.
    The second row contains field specs: (type, size, decimal places).
    Subsequent rows contain the data records.
    If a record is marked as deleted, it is skipped.

    File should be opened for binary reads.

    """
    # See DBF format spec at:
    #     http://www.pgts.com.au/download/public/xbase.htm#DBF_STRUCT

    numrec, lenheader = struct.unpack('<xxxxLH22x', f.read(32))    
    numfields = (lenheader - 33) // 32

    fields = []
    for fieldno in xrange(numfields):
        name, typ, size, deci = struct.unpack('<11sc4xBB14x', f.read(32))
        name = name.replace('\0', '')       # eliminate NULs from string   
        fields.append((name, typ, size, deci))
    yield [field[0] for field in fields]
    yield [tuple(field[1:]) for field in fields]

    terminator = f.read(1)
    assert terminator == '\r'

    fields.insert(0, ('DeletionFlag', 'C', 1, 0))
    fmt = ''.join(['%ds' % fieldinfo[2] for fieldinfo in fields])
    fmtsiz = struct.calcsize(fmt)
    for i in xrange(numrec):
        record = struct.unpack(fmt, f.read(fmtsiz))
        if record[0] != ' ':
            continue                        # deleted record
        result = []
        for (name, typ, size, deci), value in itertools.izip(fields, record):
            if name == 'DeletionFlag':
                continue
            if typ == "N":
                value = value.replace('\0', '').lstrip()
                value = value.replace(' ', '').lstrip()
                if value == '':
                    value = 0

                elif deci:
                    value = decimal.Decimal(value)
                else:
                    value = int(value)
            elif typ == 'DATE':
                y, m, d = int(value[:4]), int(value[4:6]), int(value[6:8])
                value = datetime.date(y, m, d)
            elif typ == 'L':
                value = (value in 'YyTt' and 'T') or (value in 'NnFf' and 'F') or '?'
            elif typ == 'F':
                value = float(value)
            result.append(value)
        yield result

def dbfwriter(f, fieldnames, fieldspecs, records):

    """ Return a string suitable for writing directly to a binary dbf file.

    File f should be open for writing in a binary mode.

    Fieldnames should be no longer than ten characters and not include \x00.
    Fieldspecs are in the form (type, size, deci) where
        type is one of:
            C for ascii character data
            M for ascii character memo data (real memo fields not supported)
            D for datetime objects
            N for ints or decimal objects
            L for logical values 'T', 'F', or '?'
        size is the field width
        deci is the number of decimal places in the provided decimal object
    Records can be an iterable over the records (sequences of field values).

    """
    # header info
    ver = 3
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    yr, mon, day = now.year-1900, now.month, now.day
    numrec = len(records)
    numfields = len(fieldspecs)
    lenheader = numfields * 32 + 33
    lenrecord = sum(field[1] for field in fieldspecs) + 1
    hdr = struct.pack('<BBBBLHH20x', ver, yr, mon, day, numrec, lenheader, lenrecord)
    f.write(hdr)

    # field specs
    for name, (typ, size, deci) in itertools.izip(fieldnames, fieldspecs):
        name = name.ljust(11, '\x00')
        fld = struct.pack('<11sc4xBB14x', name, typ, size, deci)
        f.write(fld)

    # terminator
    f.write('\r')

    # records
    for record in records:
        f.write(' ')                        # deletion flag
        for (typ, size, deci), value in itertools.izip(fieldspecs, record):
            if typ == "N":
                value = str(value).rjust(size, ' ')

            elif typ == 'DATE':
                value = value.strftime('%Y%m%d')
            elif typ == 'L':
                value = str(value)[0].upper()
            else:
                value = str(value)[:size].ljust(size, ' ')
            #assert len(value) == size
            f.write(value)
        if num_lists >= 0:
                yoloOne.append(int(float(record[xone])))#Data List
        if num_lists >= 2:
                yolotwo.append(int(float(record[xtwo])))#Data List
        if num_lists >= 3:
                yolothree.append(int(float(record[xthree])))#Data List
        if num_lists >= 4:
                yolofour.append(int(float(record[xfour])))#Data List
        if num_lists >= 5:
                yolofive.append(int(float(record[xfive])))#Data List
        if num_lists >= 6:
                yolosix.append(int(float(record[xsix])))#Data List
        if daytime == "yes" or daytime == "y" or daytime == "YES" or daytime == "Yes" or daytime == "Y" :
                yoloies.append(record[1])  #Time list  

                yolos.append(int(record[0])) #Date list
    # End of file
    f.write('\x1A')


# -------------------------------------------------------
# Example calls

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys, csv
    from cStringIO import StringIO
    from operator import itemgetter

    seen = set()
    # Read a database
    for x in ROfiles:
        if x not in seen:
            yoloies = []
            yoloOne = []
            yolotwo = []
            yolothree = []
            yolofour = []
            yolofive = []
            yolosix = []
            yolos = [] 
            seen.add(x)
            filename = 'C:\Users\jcm\Desktop\RO\\'+x
            print filename
            if len(sys.argv) == 2:
                filename = sys.argv[1]
            f = open(filename, 'rb')
            db = list(dbfreader(f))
            f.close()
            #for record in db:
                #print record
            fieldnames, fieldspecs, records = db[0], db[1], db[2:]

            # Alter the database
            #del records[0]
            #records.sort(key=itemgetter(4))

            # Remove a field
            #del fieldnames[3]
            #del fieldspecs[3]
            #records = [rec[1:] for rec in records]

            # Create a new DBF
            f = StringIO()
            dbfwriter(f, fieldnames, fieldspecs, records)
            #Create a new csv
            print yoloOne

            if num_lists == 0 or num_lists == 1:
                    if daytime == "yes" or daytime == "y" or daytime == "YES" or daytime == "Yes" or daytime == "Y" :

                            with open(Nameoutput+".csv", "ab") as out_file:

                                for date, time, intensityone in zip(yolos, yoloies, yoloOne):

                                    out_file.write("%i,%s,%i\n" % (date, time, intensityone))
                                print "done"
                    else:
                            with open(Nameoutput+".csv", "ab") as out_file:

                                for  intensityone,in zip(yoloOne):

                                    out_file.write("%i,\n" % ( intensityone))
                                print "done"

            if num_lists == 2:
                    if daytime == "yes" or daytime == "y" or daytime == "YES" or daytime == "Yes" or daytime == "Y" :

                            with open(Nameoutput+".csv", "ab") as out_file:

                                for date, time, intensityone, intensitytwo in zip(yolos, yoloies, yoloOne, yolotwo):

                                    out_file.write("%i,%s,%i,%i\n" % (date, time, intensityone, intensitytwo))
                                print "done"
                    else:
                            with open(Nameoutput+".csv", "ab") as out_file:

                                for  intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree in zip(yoloOne, yolotwo):

                                    out_file.write("%i,%i\n" % ( intensityone, intensitytwo))
                                print "done"

            if num_lists == 3:
                    if daytime == "yes" or daytime == "y" or daytime == "YES" or daytime == "Yes" or daytime == "Y" :

                            with open(Nameoutput+".csv", "ab") as out_file:

                                for date, time, intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree in zip(yolos, yoloies, yoloOne, yolotwo, yolothree):

                                    out_file.write("%i,%s,%i,%i,%i\n" % (date, time, intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree))
                                print "done"
                    else:
                            with open(Nameoutput+".csv", "ab") as out_file:

                                for  intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree in zip(yoloOne, yolotwo, yolothree):

                                    out_file.write("%i,%i,%i\n" % ( intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree))
                                print "done"
            if num_lists == 4:
                    if daytime == "yes" or daytime == "y" or daytime == "YES" or daytime == "Yes" or daytime == "Y" :

                            with open(Nameoutput+".csv", "ab") as out_file:

                                for date, time, intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree, intensityfour  in zip(yolos, yoloies, yoloOne, yolotwo, yolothree, yolofour):

                                    out_file.write("%i,%s,%i,%i,%i,%i\n" % (date, time, intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree, intensityfour ))
                                print "done"
                    else:
                            with open(Nameoutput+".csv", "ab") as out_file:

                                for  intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree, intensityfour in zip(yoloOne, yolotwo, yolothree, yolofour):

                                    out_file.write("%i,%i,%i,%i\n" % ( intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree, intensityfour))
                                print "done"
            if num_lists == 5:
                    if daytime == "yes" or daytime == "y" or daytime == "YES" or daytime == "Yes" or daytime == "Y" :

                            with open(Nameoutput+".csv", "ab") as out_file:

                                for date, time, intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree, intensityfour, intensityfive in zip(yolos, yoloies, yoloOne, yolotwo, yolothree, yolofour, yolofive):

                                    out_file.write("%i,%s,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i\n" % (date, time, intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree, intensityfour, intensityfive ))
                                print "done"
                    else:
                            with open(Nameoutput+".csv", "ab") as out_file:

                                for  intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree, intensityfour, intensityfive  in zip(yoloOne, yolotwo, yolothree, yolofour, yolofive ):

                                    out_file.write("%i,%i,%i,%i,%i\n" % ( intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree, intensityfour, intensityfive))
                                print "done"

            if num_lists >= 6:
                    if daytime == "yes" or daytime == "y" or daytime == "YES" or daytime == "Yes" or daytime == "Y" :

                            with open(Nameoutput+".csv", "ab") as out_file:

                                for date, time, intensity in zip(yolos, yoloies, yoloOne, yolotwo, yolothree, yolofour, yolofive, yolosix ):

                                    out_file.write("%i,%s,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i\n" % (date, time, intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree, intensityfour, intensityfive, intensitysix))
                                print "done"
                    else:
                            with open(Nameoutput+".csv", "ab") as out_file:

                                for intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree, intensityfour, intensityfive, intensitysix in zip(yoloOne, yolotwo, yolothree, yolofour, yolofive, yolosix ):

                                    out_file.write("%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i\n" % ( intensityone, intensitytwo, intensitythree, intensityfour, intensityfive, intensitysix))
                                print "done"
```